# if...else not working on Node.JS route (Deducting from Balances etc.)

Tags: node.js, rest

I appear to be having some problem with the if.... else statement on this node.js / express REST api.
Now here is what, when i make the request and test on Postman it sends the request without challenges, but the money does not deduct from the wallet, no idea why this is so.

My code is looking like this

```
router.post("/intl-transfer", async (req, res, next) => {
  let output_amount = 0;
  try {
    if (
      !req.headers.authorization ||
      !req.headers.authorization.startsWith("Bearer ") ||
      !req.headers.authorization.split(" ")[1]
    ) {
      return res.status(422).json({ message: "Please Provide Token!" });
    }

    var source_currency = "NGN";
    var account_bank = req.body.account_bank;
    var beneficiary_name = req.body.beneficiary_name;
    var account_number = req.body.account_number;
    var amount = req.body.amount;
    var narration = req.body.narration;
    var currency2 = currency;
    var sender = req.body.sender;
    var sender_country = req.body.sender_country;
    var mobile_number = req.body.mobile_number;
    var currency = req.body.currency;

    if (currency == "KES") {
      //Make HttpRequest to get the exchange currency before anything
      var header = {
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Content-type": "application/json",
        Authorization: "Bearer FLWSECK_TEST-153740d351951b5f6d5ae8b903e0c467-X",
      };

      var convert_url = `https://api.flutterwave.com/v3/transfers/rates?amount=${amount}&destination_currency=${currency}&source_currency=${source_currency}`;

      const response = await fetch(convert_url, { method: "GET", headers: header });
      const responseJson = await response.json();
      if (responseJson.message == "Transfer amount fetched") {
        //console.log("Amount : "+responseJson.data.source.amount);
        output_amount = responseJson.data.source.amount;
        url = "https://api.flutterwave.com/v3/transfers";
        await fetch(url, {
          method: "POST",
          headers: {
            Accept: "application/json",
            "Content-type": "application/json",
            Authorization:
              "Bearer FLWSECK_TEST-153740d351951b5f6d5ae8b903e0c467-X",
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({
            account_bank: account_bank,
            account_number: account_number,
            beneficiary_name: beneficiary_name,
            amount: amount,
            narration: narration,
            currency: currency2,
            meta: [
              {
                sender: sender,
                sender_country: sender_country,
                mobile_number: mobile_number,
              },
            ],
          }),
        })
          .then((response) => response.json())
          .then(async (json) => {
            const debit = await User.find({ email: req.body.email });
            const debit_balance = debit[0].balance;
            const debit_amt = debit_balance - output_amount;
            await User.findOneAndUpdate(
              { email: email },
              { $set: { balance: debit_amt } }
            );

            const transactions = new Trans({
              email: req.body.email,
              narration: narration,
              credit: 0.0,
              debit: amount,
              amount: amount,
            });
            try {
              //sendTransferNotification(email);
              SendFXTransferNotification(
                req.body.email,
                beneficiary_name,
                amount
              );
              transactions.save();
              //res.send(savedUser);
              console.log("transaction saved");
            } catch (err) {
              //res.status(400).send(err);
              console.log(err);
            }

            //sendTransferConfirmation(email);
            return res.send({ error: false, data: json, message: "OK" });
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            throw err;
          });
      }
    } else {
      var account_bank = req.body.account_bank;
      var account_number = req.body.account_number;
      var amount = output_amount;
      var narration = req.body.narration;
      var email = req.body.email;
      var currency = req.body.currency;
      var destination_branch_code = req.body.destination_branch_code;
      var reference = req.body.refernce;
      var debit_currency = req.body.debit_currency;
      var beneficiary_name = req.body.beneficiary_name;

      //Make HttpRequest to get the exchange currency before anything

      var header = {
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Content-type": "application/json",
        Authorization:
          "Bearer FLWSECK-22b1e86e9882b63a8bc4c1f9cc940675-187b20352d9vt-X",
      };

      var convert_url = `https://api.flutterwave.com/v3/transfers/rates?amount=${amount}&destination_currency=${currency}&source_currency=${source_currency}`;

      const response = await fetch(convert_url, { method: "GET", headers: header });
      const responseJson = await response.json();
      if (responseJson.message == "Transfer amount fetched") {
        output_amount = responseJson.data.source.amount;
        url = "https://api.flutterwave.com/v3/transfers";
        await fetch(url, {
          method: "POST",
          headers: {
            Accept: "application/json",
            "Content-type": "application/json",
            Authorization:
              "Bearer FLWSECK-22b1e86e9882b63a8bc4c1f9cc940675-187b20352d9vt-X",
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({
            account_bank: account_bank,
            account_number: account_number,
            amount: output_amount,
            narration: narration,
            currency: currency,
            destination_branch_code: destination_branch_code,
            reference: reference,
            debit_currency: debit_currency,
            beneficiary_name: beneficiary_name,
          }),
        })
          .then((response) => response.json())
          .then(async (json) => {
            const debit = await User.find({ email: req.body.email });
            const debit_balance = debit[0].balance;
            const debit_amt = debit_balance - output_amount;
            await User.findOneAndUpdate(
              { email: email },
              { $set: { balance: debit_amt } }
            );

            const transactions = new Trans({
              email: req.body.email,
              narration: narration,
              credit: 0.0,
              debit: amount,
              amount: amount,
            });
            try {
              SendFXTransferNotification(
                req.body.email,
                beneficiary_name,
                amount
              );
              transactions.save();
              //res.send(savedUser);
              console.log("transaction saved");
            } catch (err) {
              //res.status(400).send(err);
              console.log(err);
            }

            //sendTransferConfirmation(email);
            return res.send({ error: false, data: json, message: "OK" });
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            throw err;
          });
      }
    }
  } catch (err) {
    next(err);
  }
});
```

I understand its Long, it just does the request but from the Wallet it does not deduct money from the wallet in this case. Please Help. What could be the issue?

Comment: Which of the many `if` are you talking about? Have you tried using a debugger and stepping through your code? Where does it not behave as expected?

Comment: the if to check if its KES, or else not KES

Comment: Well, attach a debugger and check the value of `req.body.currency`. do you have an appropriate body parser attached?

Comment: @derpirscher , No i do not